# Audio stream from phone to pc via serial port in C#

Tags: c#, audio, mobile, stream, serial-port

I'm looking for a way to stream audio from a phone directly to the pc. I'm not talking about music or something but every sound of the phone (voice, ringing etc). Is this possible over an USB cable and the Serial Port of the PC without using third party tools or libraries? I'm currently developing in C#.

Comment: Maybe you can connect 3.5mm output of phone to microphone input of PC and then try to record microphone input in C#?

Comment: I guess recording would work over C# mciSendString am I right? Does this really work with the 3.5mm output?

Comment: There are generally two sets of APIs to record input, WinMM API (mciSendString is part of it) and WSAPI (Windows Vista and later). There are also libraries to do that. It should work with the 3.5mm output but I haven't test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! Do not connect your phone line to the microphone port. The high voltage on the line (60-120V when ringing) may damage your PC.

What you need is a PHONE-to-LINE in adaptor (or sometimes PHONE-TO-MIC adapter) found in electronic stores. Here is an example from AMAZON:
[http://www.amazon.com/TRX-20-Direct-Connect-Telephone-ADAPTER/dp/B000KL0XA6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1459033666&sr=8-1&keywords=phone+recording+device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000KL0XA6) (I have no ties or experience with this particular one).

Then, your plug it in to your PC's LINE-IN or MIC (see instructions of the device). From this point on you should be able to record the audio from a call using any sound recording application.

Please keep in mind that PHONE recording may be illegal in some states, if the parties involved are not informed.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I wanted. By the way. I don't want to record voice directly. I want to check out if a phone number is dead or still alive. it seem not to work with AT commands on smartphone so I have to somehow record sound to discover if the phone is ringing or not.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to detect if a telephone number exists, your method may be intrusive, since it will attempt a call.

In any case, a voice modem could be a better choice, assuming you can find one. Windows used to have a voice modem API & Stack, which should enable you to dial a phone number, wait for the answer or no answer, and then, capture the audio from the remote end. Under most conditions it should detect the ring, busy, or number not available.

The open source project Asterisk (asterisk.org) has "heavy duty machinery" to do this job, albeit it requires specialised programming. There is even an answering machine detection: [Asterisk Answering machine detection (AMD) always detects receiver as MACHINE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714996/asterisk-answering-machine-detection-amd-always-detects-receiver-as-machine)